# How to disable boot messages on startup?

Tags: grub2, gentoo, bootsplash

I am running Gentoo currently. I don't want to see the boot messages it shows me. My `/etc/default/grub` has these lines: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash"` and `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`, and updated grub with `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

It still shows me boot messages. Do I have to do something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GRUB2:

> The grub-mkconfig script is used to generate a grub configuration. It uses the scripts under /etc/grub.d/* together with the /etc/default/grub configuration file to generate the final /boot/grub/grub.cfg - the only configuration file used by GRUB2 itself.

So you need to do that by running something like

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: Of course I have done that... I have edited my question to include that.

Comment: `quiet` hides diagnostic messages but not everything. Do you mean you still see the normal quiet output? What do you want to see instead?

Comment: Yes I see the normal boot messages like the loading of OpenRC. I want to see, maybe an image instead?

Comment: You have `splash` already so it sounds like you're missing Plymouth and an appropriate theme then.